# TIFF File Download Automation in EarthExplorer

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, download

I'm working on a project to download cropped tiff files for the following area from this website https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/.

[image]

The crop will generate 417 datasets (tiff files) which are divided into 10 pages and ready to be downloaded by clicking the download icon in the following image.

[image]

Then a choice of file formats to download will appear and I choose GeoTIFF 1 Arc-second Download.

[image]

The website requires login to download the files.

Because there are too many files that I have to download, I want to automate the download process. I have used selenium and chrome web driver in python to do this task. But due to limited information I have not been able to complete it.

Any suggestions on how to finish this job? Or is there a similar project reference? Your information means a lot to me. Thank you